# Is it possible to autocorrect words?

Tags: feature-request, editing

Is it possible for SE to correct words according to a list or something?

Example:

- IOS, Ios ios should be iOS
- IPAD, ipad, Ipad, IPad etc should be iPad
- apple should be Apple

These "mistakes" occur many times resulting in edits. I don't mind editing them, but if it is technically possible...?

Comment: hey, newbies like me gotta get points somehow ;)

Comment: @dwightk I fully understand you'd like to get points ASAP. But just editing for IPad to iPad is a bit pointless IMO. I did accept your edit though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cosmetically-infuriating as these typos can be, they don't obscure the meaning or intent behind a question or answer so I would just: don't sweat it. I think you'll go a little crazy trying to right all those wrongs on this site if you can't find a way to live with them.

Comment: Or, to put it the other way round: If you take on the mission on fixing all Ipads, IPADS etc. please pick those posts which are in need of editing for other reasons as well :-)